# unable to install tensorflow and wrapt obstructing

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, wrapt

I got the solution for the same issue from this Stackoverflow earlier(couple of months back) but I forgot it.

The solution should be like this: download the wrapt package from GitHub and placed the same in c: drive \ user profile location \wrapt.

while installing the tensorflow package, wrapt obstructing it

```
pip install tensorflow
```

error while installing the tensorflow

`Installing collected packages: wrapt, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can either uninstall and reinstall wrap or simply upgrade.

first uninstall wrapt:

```
 pip uninstall wrapt
```

Then reinstall:

```
 pip install wrapt
```

Or simply (then you don't have to install and uninstall):

```
 pip install wrapt --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

Then:

```
 pip install tensorflow
```